# HTML in Azure Blob Storage fails to load favicon (Error 400)

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-ad-b2c

In order to use [custom UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-ui-customization-custom) in my Azure AD B2C policy, I've uploaded an HTML file to Azure Blob Storage, that I would then provide to Azure AD B2C.

The problem is that Azure AD B2C won't accept my HTML because it loads with an error.

When I load the HTML page from Blob in the browser and go to the Chrome console,
I see this error

```
GET https://myb2cstorage.blob.core.windows.net/favicon.ico 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.)
```

The HTML loads fine, but this one error prevents me from using it in AD B2C.

What can be the issue?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you configured CORS ?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, it still didn't work. I think that I've figured out what to do. I've created a "static website" (In the storage account menu), and then when I access the HTML page via the URL of the static website, I don't get that error.

Comment: Good to know :-) you should share your learning as an answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

It is best to [add a favicon to the page](https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon) using the `rel` attribute of a `link` element in the `head` section rather than having to locate the favicon file at a predefined URI:

```html
<link href="https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
```